# How can I integrate this JS into my GTM tracking?

Tags: canvas, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to send custom dimensions through my GTM with Google Analytics. I tried following a recipe that provides a custom JS. However I get this error:

> JavaScript compiler error
> Custom js
> Error at line 2, character 20: Parse error. ')' expected

What can I try to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
// Pull activity type based on urlfunction 
identifyActivity() {
  
var url = document.location.href, activityType = 'unknown'; 
if (url.indexOf('/pages/') > -1) { activityType = 'Content Page'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/pages') > -1) { activityType = 'Content Pages List'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/assignments/syllabus') > -1) { activityType = 'Syllabus'; d} 
  else if (url.indexOf('/assignments/') > -1) { activityType = 'Assignment'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/assignments') > -1) { activityType = 'Assignment List'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/discussion_topics/') > -1) { activityType = 'Discussion'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/discussion_topics') > -1) { activityType = 'Discussion List'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/files') > -1) { activityType = 'Files'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/grades') > -1) { activityType = 'Grades'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/announcements') > -1) { activityType = 'Announcements'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/users') > -1) { activityType = 'People'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/outcomes') > -1) { activityType = 'Outcomes'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/quizzes/') > -1) { activityType = 'Quiz'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/quizzes') > -1) { activityType = 'Quizzes List'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/modules') > -1) { activityType = 'Modules List'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/conferences') > -1) { activityType = 'Conferences'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/collaborations') > -1) { activityType = 'Collaborations'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/external_tools/') > -1) { activityType = 'External Tool'; } 
  else if (typeof ENV.COURSE_HOME !== undefined) { activityType = 'Course Home'; } 
return activityType;
}‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍
```

Also the recipe is here: https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Admin-Group/Google-Analytics-Custom-Dimensions-through-Google-Tag-Manager/m-p/265830

Answer (score 0):

Use this construct:

```
function() {
var url = document.location.href, activityType = 'unknown'; 
if (url.indexOf('/pages/') > -1) { activityType = 'Content Page'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/pages') > -1) { activityType = 'Content Pages List'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/assignments/syllabus') > -1) { activityType = 'Syllabus'; d} 
  else if (url.indexOf('/assignments/') > -1) { activityType = 'Assignment'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/assignments') > -1) { activityType = 'Assignment List'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/discussion_topics/') > -1) { activityType = 'Discussion'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/discussion_topics') > -1) { activityType = 'Discussion List'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/files') > -1) { activityType = 'Files'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/grades') > -1) { activityType = 'Grades'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/announcements') > -1) { activityType = 'Announcements'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/users') > -1) { activityType = 'People'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/outcomes') > -1) { activityType = 'Outcomes'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/quizzes/') > -1) { activityType = 'Quiz'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/quizzes') > -1) { activityType = 'Quizzes List'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/modules') > -1) { activityType = 'Modules List'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/conferences') > -1) { activityType = 'Conferences'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/collaborations') > -1) { activityType = 'Collaborations'; } 
  else if (url.indexOf('/external_tools/') > -1) { activityType = 'External Tool'; } 
  else if (typeof ENV.COURSE_HOME !== undefined) { activityType = 'Course Home'; } 
return activityType;
}
```